# The Silverlight DataPager never gives me a page count greater than 1.

Tags: silverlight, pagination

I've decided that RIA Services is way too limiting and am attempting to role my own server side pagination.  I've long since switched over to plain old WCF. Everything is going wonderfully.  My only problem, ironically, is with the front end. I'm trying to get the `DataPager` control to work. I could have (and it seems should have) created my own `DataPager` control, but I didn't want to take the time to write something as nice as the `DataPager` is (the control itself, not the client side query nonsense). The trouble I face, probably obviously, is setting the page count within the pager. It seems that the data pager is automagically tied to RIA services. I've tried creating an implementation of `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` that only references a count (i.e. returns n of default(T)).  I've tried using arrays of integers.  All of these techniques are very wasteful and whats more, they don't work. I am to the point where it would have been much faster to write my own data pager than to use this one. So I thought I'd ask what I'm doing wrong (i.e. though I know that ultimately my wrong is in using this control without the beloved RIA client side query at all).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I wasn't using the `PagedCollectionView`.